# stored procedure updating two tables with different id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have stored procedure like this:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[delivary] @dedate nvarchar(100), 
                                 @carid nvarchar(100), 
                                 @transid integer as
begin
    select t.transactID 
      from Transaction_tbl t 
     where t.TBarcode = @carid
    update Transaction_tbl 
       set DelDate = '' + @dedate + '', Status=5 
     where TBarcode = @carid
    update KHanger_tbl 
       set Delivered=1 
     where transactid=@transid
end
```

I am able to update my transaction table. 
I also want to update the table `KHanger_table` with a `TransactID` matching `@carid`.

How i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
alter procedure [dbo].[delivary] 
    (@dedate nvarchar(100), 
    @carid nvarchar(100))
    AS
    begin
        DECLARE @transactID int;
        SET @transactID = (select t.transactID 
          from Transaction_tbl t 
         where t.TBarcode = @carid);

        update Transaction_tbl 
           set DelDate = '' + @dedate + '', Status=5 
         where TBarcode = @carid

        update KHanger_tbl 
           set Delivered=1 
         where transactid=@transactID
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 ways you can do it :

First Retrieving and storing your transactID in a variable :

```
alter procedure [dbo].[delivary] @dedate nvarchar(100), 
                                 @carid nvarchar(100)as
begin
    declare @transid int
    select @transid = t.transactID 
      from Transaction_tbl t 
     where t.TBarcode = @carid

    update Transaction_tbl 
       set DelDate = '' + @dedate + '', Status=5 
     where TBarcode = @carid

    update KHanger_tbl 
       set Delivered=1 
     where transactid=@transid
end
```

And you have the relational update :

```
alter procedure [dbo].[delivary] @dedate nvarchar(100), 
                                 @carid nvarchar(100) as
begin
    update Transaction_tbl 
       set DelDate = '' + @dedate + '', Status=5 
     where TBarcode = @carid

    update KHt
      set KHt.Delivered=1
    from KHanger_tbl as KHt
      inner join Transaction_tbl t
        on KHt.transactionid = t.transactID
    where t.TBarcode = @carid
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (shorter) way to do it:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[delivary] 
(@dedate nvarchar(100), 
@carid nvarchar(100))
AS
begin
    DECLARE @transactID int;

    update Transaction_tbl 
       set DelDate = @dedate, Status=5, @transactID = transactID 
     where TBarcode = @carid

    update KHanger_tbl 
       set Delivered=1 
     where transactid=@transactID
end
```

Also, you probably want to do the 2 updates in a transaction so either both succeed or none at all.